# Bootstrap 4 navigation active link state

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, kirby

I use bootstrapv4 navigation, but when I click on an item, the active state doesn't switch.
I tried some js but none of them are working.
I'm using kirby cms, but i don't this is causing any problems..
Could using `<?php snippet('header')?>` cause the trouble?
Or am I setting it up wrong?

This ist my header.php

```html
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg pl-3 pr-3 pl-lg-5 pr-lg-5">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <a class="logo-link" href="<?= $site->url() ?>"><?php if($image = $site->image('logo.png')): ?>
                        <img class="logo-image mr-5" src="<?= $image->url() ?>" alt="logo"><?php endif ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler pt-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="toggleFunction(this)">
                <div class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <?php $menuCounter=0;
                    foreach ($site->children()->listed() as $subpage):
                        $menuCounter++;
                        $class = ($menuCounter == 1) ? "active" : "inactive";
                        $span = ($menuCounter == 1) ? "<span class='sr-only'>(current)</span>" : "";
                        ?>
                        <li class="<?php echo $class ?> nav-item">
                            <a class="menu-point nav-link" href="<?= $subpage->url() ?>"><?= $subpage->title() ?><?= $span ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons nav-icons">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

This is my js-file

```
$(".nav-item").on("click", function(){
        $(".nav-item").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: in JS try this
$(".nav-item").on("click", function(){
        $(".navbar-nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

Answer (score 0):

You dont need Javacript for that in Kirby. You can use a helper like this within you foreach loop:

```
<li class="menu-item<?= r($subpage->isOpen(), ' active') ?>">
```

More Infos about the helpers and the isOpen-object:
https://getkirby.com/docs/reference/templates/helpers
https://getkirby.com/docs/reference/objects/page/is-open